# Show that for any a ∈ C − {0}, there exists a logarithm function defined on D(a, |a|).

Tags: complex-analysis

We made use of the following proposition:

for f(z) to be logarithm function, two conditions need to be satisfied

1. $f\prime(z) = \frac{1}{z}$
2. there exists $z_{0} $ such that $ e^{f(z_{0})} = z_{0} $

for any $ D(a,\vert a \vert$), we seek to construct an logarithm function in the following two manners.

1. define an artificial domain $\Omega = D(a,\vert a \vert$), and let f(z) = $\frac{1}{2}log(x^2+y^2)+i*arctan(\frac{y}{x})$, it can be easily verfied that two conditions are held, and we have found such logarithm function.
2. I try to construct a more easily accessible example. Think of $ f(z) = \sum_{n=1}\frac{(−1)^{n−1}}{n}(z − 1)^n $, it satisfies condition (1) and (2) as well, but it only holds for $D(1,\vert 1 \vert$). Now, what if we modified it a little, like changing the 1 to a so that we can cook up another logarithm function? Or is the example in 1 unique?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not define your function as $f(x) = \int_a^x dx/x?$ The integral is defined over an arbitrary path (they are all the same by monodromy, since the domain is simply connected and does not contain zero).

Comment: Bad notation.${}$

Comment: @KentaS What you mean to say is "I think this is bad notation". Noted.